# use javascript in rails 3.2 without coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm using Rails 3.2, It's set up for coffeescript. I know Coffeescript is an awesome language and it's not too hard to learn, but i'm JUST starting to wrap my head around Javascript and jQuery. So my question is this: Is there an easy way to set rails 3.2 up to use Javascript instead?
At the moment, my jQuery is in `<script></script>` tags in my view (timeline/index.html.erb). I'd like to move it into a .js file. I tried changing the name of my timeline.js.coffee to just timeline.js and putting the jQuery in there, but I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

What should I do besides the obvious answer of "learn coffeescript"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was on the right track. To switch to javascript in rails 3.2 you only need to remove the `.coffee` extension. However, you also need to make sure you use `//` for comments instead of `#`

```
//# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
//# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
//# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Manifest Files and Directives**
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

add js files in app/assets/javascripts, then add the files in `application.js`

---

your js file

```
alert("here");
```

application.js

```
//= require_tree .
or
//= require your_js_file_name
```

---

then, it will be picked up from the code below in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: it's all set up that way by default. except that the default filese are `.js.coffee` and i tried to change it to `.js`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.11
```

how about this?
http://bit.ly/VHEnBX

```
git clone it
cd js_test
bundle
rails s -d
open http://localhost:3000

# stop the detached server 
kill -9 `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`
```

you should see `here` alert from the browser.

it's just a simple js file.  no .coffee extension or whatsoever.
http://bit.ly/UPe2mp

Answer (score 0):

you can simply comment out gem 'coffee-rails' in your Gemfile

Comment: It still should recognize .js as javascript with or without coffee-rails. Which it does.