# Converting JavaScript to Coffee?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

In a Rails project with only a Coffee file, can I add a JavaScript file?

If not, am I supposed to convert each JavaScript file to Coffee?

Comment: coffee -> js if you add nothing happen))

Comment: @Monk_Code sorry I didn't understand what you mean !

Comment: The golden rule of CoffeeScript is: "It's just JavaScript".!

Comment: You can see this question [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658606/use-javascript-in-rails-3-2-without-coffeescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use both `JavaScript` and `Coffee` files side-by-side in a Rails 3/4 app.

Coffee files are just a convenience.  They are all compiled to browser-compatible `JavaScript` files when the application is run.

So, using a `JavaScript` file is acceptable.  The Asset pipeline will know how to handle both appropriately.

This depends on the 'coffee-rails' gem being present in your Gemfile.